# What is the physical meaning of the voltage across an inductor in the Laplace domain?

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, differential, laplace-transform

In my Electrical Engineering degree I recently learned how to analyse circuits using Laplace transforms and I know that the Laplace transform of the voltage across an inductor is \$V_L(s) =s*L*I(s) - L*i(0)\$, but I don't understand its physical meaning. I know that \$s*L\$ is the impedance so with Ohm's law we get \$V_L(s) =s*L*I(s)\$ but when it gets to subtracting \$L*i(0)\$ I don't understand where it comes from, I know it is supposed to represent the initial voltage but shouldn't it be also \$s*L*i(0)\$ ?

Comment: All terms having an *s* in the laplace domain are time-dependent in the time domain. So, no, initial values cannot have an *s*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplace transform of a derivative is

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{ \frac{dy}{dt} \right\} = s\mathcal{L}\left\{f\right\} - y(0^+)$$

Ie. \$y(0^+)\$ is the initial condition, for time approaching zero from the right side.

Since the "law" of inductors is

$$v_L = L\cdot \frac{di_L}{dt}$$

Its Laplace transform is given by

$$\begin{align}
V_L(s) &= L\left( sI_L(s) - i_L(0^+) \right) \\
&= Ls\cdot I_L(s) - L\cdot i_L(0^+)
&\Downarrow \\
I_L(s) &= \frac{V_L(s)}{Ls} + \frac{i_L(0^+)}{s}
\end{align}$$

So in this formula, \$i_L(0^+)\$ takes the meaning of the initial current through the inductor. From the last equation, you also can assign a physical meaning to it. This equation coincides to having a parallel constant current source with the inductor!

In other words, you can replace an inductor with

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvGAwx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a capacitor, the same can be done. It will result in putting a constant voltage source in series with the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're in the Laplace domain now. You're dealing in terms of frequency. If you did take the Laplace transform of an initial condition, the constant divided by an 'integrator' or a [delta function](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Laplace-transform-of-a-constant). This delta function is also placed at zero in the Laplace world (which is DC in terms of frequency)

$${\mathcal{L}(c) = \dfrac{c}{s}} = \delta $$

This makes total sense, if you have a constant value, it's pretty much a DC value, if you want to know which frequency its at zero frequency, there is no frequency because it's constant.

[image]

So across an inductor this would signify that there was already something there before the system started, but it wouldn't make a lot of sense until you transform it back into the time domain, you can also think of it as a placeholder.

Comment: Agreed on all but *frequency*. *s* doesn't represent a frequency because of the ability of the Laplace domain to image real exponents of e.

Comment: Technically no, but it's a close analog to the FFT

Comment: Yes, sure, I am nitpicking. But this is the case where it really matters! Because the OP wanted to know the difference between a static value and a one-time signal. The latter **has** an *s* in the laplace domain. The frequency analogy will simply say "it's **all** frequencies as it's a jump" but this is even more mysterious.

Comment: Actually they do call s the complex number frequency parameter.

Comment: Yes, but as my control theory teacher put it: "Gee, what's that supposed to mean?" It's obstructive, not helping at all.